# Sourcing El Rey chocolate (or substitute) in the UK

Tags: substitutions, chocolate

I used to buy El Rey Gran Saman (70%) and Mijao (61%) Venezuelan chocolate in the UK in 5kg boxes of discs. My previous supplier is delisting El Rey and selling off -- albeit not at a reduced price -- their remaining stock. They have no Mijao left and the best they can do is 20kg of Gran Saman with a use by date of the end of September (i.e., three weeks)! El Rey have a US site -- and I've found other US stockists -- but they don't deliver to the UK (besides, the shipping would likely make it unviable).

This is perhaps not suitable for Seasoned Advice, but does anyone know where I can get some Mijao and/or Gran Saman? (I don't really need that much: 500g would be plenty.) Alternatively, can anyone recommend a substitute Venezuelan couverture in the 64% cocoa range that is readily available in the UK and is of a similar quality? (e.g., I'm not a fan of Belcolade or Callebaut. I guess, as I need a relatively small amount, I could pay over the odds for retail bars and use them as a last resort.)

Comment: Venezuelan isn't a necessity; it's just my personal preference. Anything with a fruity, low-bitterness flavour profile is good.

Comment: Have you tried Willie's Cacao? It's available via www.amazon.co.uk, reasonable prices and free shipping, and the ability to bulk order.

Comment: Willie's cacao is available in waitrose as well

Comment: I've always found Willie's Cacao quite bitter, but it's a good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found Michel Cluizel's Los Ancones, a 67% cocoa couverture sourced from the Caribbean and easily available in the UK in 1kg bags. I remember having tried this before in its retail form and it has a very fruity flavour profile, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: We aren't a forum, so asking additional questions in answers isn't how we work here. I also doubt that this question would be acceptable here at all.